# CloudKit in order to shared data between users

Tags: ios, iphone, cloudkit

I was wondering if it would be possible to create an app which would be able to share data between iOS users.

For exemple,

Basically my app would allow a user to create an "Event" and add a list of "Friends". Those would also have access to this event and they will be able to interact with this event. Plus for any critical modification, all the friends have to be notified by a push notification.

Does CloudKit have those features ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work for you, yes.

> CloudKit provides complementary services for managing the transfer of
>   data to and from iCloud servers.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CloudKit_Framework_Reference/)

Comment: Thanks, so i can create my event into a "public" data base, and all my users, if they're added by the event's owner, would be able to see it right ?

Comment: That should be possible to do @Pwyll28

Comment: I disagree, is not so simple. You can't search for your friends, unless they mark himself as discoverable. In CK all user are IDs, uniques for your app and you can't search in the Users records (from your app). Also, your friend should subscribe to the event list they are interested, because otherwise anyone could send spam in your app. Finally, if you give access to modified the record created by one user to other "logged users" is dangerous (IMHO). Ah, don't forget about sensitive data, this is a public database, a danger exists of other user read the events of other users.